# ReactJS: how listen that child component updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a 3rd-party component in my application. And I want to perform some actions in the parent component when it's child component updates (i.e. fires `componentDidUpdate`) but it turns out parent component's `componentDidUpdate` doesn't fire when the child updates internally.

Is there anyway to listen from the parent that the child component has updated? Assuming that I **can't modify the child component** code.

Comment: You can fire a callback when the child updates - can you identify the point when you want the parent to update?

Comment: That depends on why the child component is updating

Comment: @Alex I have already identified the point when I want it to update but I can't modify the child component code that's why the approach with additional callback isn't possible.

Comment: Is there a variable that updates in the child at the point you want it to? Can you observe that variable to trigger a callback on the parent?

Comment: Alternatively if there is an update to the DOM you could use vanilla Javascript to look for that change and trigger an update to your state from there - many people will have this solution, but if it works and you manage state properly then I dont see a problem

Comment: thanks @Alex, I decided to go the most pure way - fork the 3rd-party library and add the missing function into it :)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to listen from the parent that the child component has updated?

The answer is: there is no way.

However, we absolutely could implement that functionality by leveraging `componentDidUpdate()` method of the child component.

We pass down a callback function as a prop from the parent component to the child component. Then whenever the child component has updated, we will invoke that callback function in the `componentDidUpdate()` method of the child component. In this way, ***the parent can listen when the child component has updated***.

Comment: It turns out you're right that there is no way. The key problem is that the component is external and I can't modify it's code that's why any approaches with callbacks don't work until these callbacks are implemented in the child component.